# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException and java.lang.IllegalArgumentException using openbravo

Tags: java, erp, openbravo

When I tried to generate a report, after I build the project, the tomcat server says

> `"SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)"`

and

> `"SEVERE: Context [/openbravo] startup failed due to previous errors"`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try to `clean Tomcat work directory` and `clean` the tomcat server. Then try once.

Comment: i try it, but didn't work, thanks,